# pandas dataframe processing

Tags: python, pandas

I have several lists with 2 dict inside a dataframe like the one below :

```
new_data[0] 

[{'code': '8', 'name': 'Human '}, {'code': '11', 'name': 'ET '}]
```

I want to count the names occurrence

```
#for i in new_data:

 #   aux_list.append(i[0]["name"])
   # aux_list.append(i[1]["name"])

#pd.DataFrame(aux_list).value_counts()
```

unfortunately, some of my name.values are empty

Is there a better way to do it ?
How to remove the nan values ?

Comment: Your code seems invalid, you mention several lists but iterate only over one, and with a different nesting level than the one described.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this input:

```
new_data = [[{'code': '8', 'name': 'Human'}, {'code': '11', 'name': 'ET'}],
            [{'code': '8', 'name': 'Human'}, {'code': '11'}],
           ]
```

You do not need pandas, use a simple [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

out = Counter(d['name'] for l in new_data for d in l if 'name' in d)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'Human': 2, 'ET': 1})
```

If you really want to use pandas, one option could be to combine [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to create an input Series for [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
from itertools import chain

out = pd.json_normalize(chain.from_iterable(new_data))['name'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Human    2
ET       1
Name: name, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

I know there is probably a better way to do this but this works:

```
import pandas as pd
new_data = [{'code': '8', 'name': ''}, {'code': '11', 'name': 'Human'}, {'code': '10', 'name': 'Animal'}, {'code': '13'}]
aux_list = []
for i in new_data:
   if "name" in i and i["name"]: aux_list.append(i["name"])
cont = pd.DataFrame(aux_list).value_counts()
print(cont)
```

output:

```
Animal    1
Human     1
dtype: int64
```